# jQuery modal dismiss function that clears out values on close, need to exclude a specific named input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a function that will reset form elements contained in a modal window when it is manually closed.

```
$('[data-dismiss=modal]').on('click', function (e) { //clears modal form errors/values on modal close
    var $t = $(this),
        target = $t[0].href || $t.data("target") || $t.parents('.modal') || [];
        $(".backend-error").html(''); //clear out previous error messages
        $('input').removeClass('input-error'); //clear error border class
    $(target)
    .find("input:not([type=hidden]),textarea,select,select:not([name=inputManufacturerModel])")
       .val('')
       .end()
    .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
       .prop("checked", "")
       .end();
})
```

I'm trying to exclude a select element named "inputManufacturerModel" from being reset via the :not selector but it's still being reset. Is my syntax wrong?

```
<select name="inputManufacturerModel" id="inputManufacturerModel" class="form-control" required="required" onclick="refreshData()">
    <option value="0">Select manufacturer...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: As you've not provided an HTML, please confirm that it is an `<input>` and not a `<textarea>`.

Comment: As you've also not provided a *snippet* that demonstrates the issue, here's a jsfiddle that shows your format of `input:not([],[])` working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/en8gdm9r/

Comment: After edit: Well, there's your answer:  `input:not([name=inputManufacturerModel])` but your "input" isn't an `input` at all, it's a `select` and your selector is `$("select")` without the `:not` part

Comment: Sorry, it's not a text input. It's a pre-populated select. Added html above.

Comment: Voting close as a typo as you've said input:not(name) instead of select:not(name)

Comment: You could also have done `$("input,select").not("[name=...]")`

Comment: I've revised. Sorry my eyes are tired. I've got 1 hidden input and the 1 select that I need excluded. I have tried revising the line to ```.find("input:not([type=hidden]),textarea,select,select:not([name=inputManufacturerModel])")``` but the select is still being cleared out on close.

Comment: `select,select:not` should be just `select:not` - take it easy and have a break :)

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks for being patient with me :)

Comment: To prevent all this, you usually clone the modal element, which you use as a template only.

Comment: @JerMah Another alternative is to re-populate/generate/build the entire modal-content each time (by getting HTML via an ajax call) but leaving the outer modal/buttons etc intact